# How to handle assertion property content for differenrt responses?

Tags: json, rest, soapui

I would like to handle assertion property content according to below responses, for both success and failure.

Success response:

```
{
   "task": "userLogin",
   "response":    {
      "code": 0,
      "status": "success",
      "error_message": "",
      "success_message": "",
      "data":       {
         "userId": "65",
         "username": "indian",
         "email": "test@gmail.com",
         "token": "b0aef6139ffdc1041e01f7587a0dcf61",
         "userType": "trial",
         "profile_picture": "test.png"
      }
   }
}
```

Failure response: will have only the `data` node missing, and remaining nodes will be present.

```
"data":       
    {
        "userId": "65",
        "username": "indian",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "token": "b0aef6139ffdc1041e01f7587a0dcf61",
        "userType": "trial",
        "profile_picture": "test.png"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a very simple XPath assertion, keeping in mind that internally SoapUI converts *everything* into XML representation.

XPath:

```
exists(//*:data)
```

Expected:

```
true
```

**Update** based on your comments.

Your original requirement was not clear. The node is present it is just empty. In that case the XPath assertion would be:

```
empty(//*:data)
```

Expected:

```
false
```

Handy [XPath reference](http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XPath_2.html).

Comment: I tried with your way.....which is working even though the "data" values displaying orelse not displaying....attachment below

Comment: I tried with your way. I got a response if the details displaying or even not displaying......see the below links.

Comment: @Satheesh Even if the node it's empty, the node itself exists so `exists(//*:data)` returns true for and `<data/>`. To check if it's not empty try adding `text()` as follows: `exists(//*:data//text())`.

Comment: @albciff...Could you please give the exact query for the below aspects.1.JsonPath Count, 2.JsonPath Existence Match, 3.JsonPath Match......It would be very helpfull for me to ahead on this

Comment: @Satheesh updated my answer based on new requirements.